# Spring Boot Active/Passive Failover Mechanism

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a Spring Boot application that houses a Camel route with an integration to our vendor.

The way our server architecture is setup, we have two nodes that the application is deployed to. However, our requirements are that we have a single instance running at a time, failing over to the secondary node when the primary goes down.

Previously, our application was deployed in a Fuse environment and this was all handled behind the scenes nicely. Is there an active/passive or clustering mechanism available for Spring Boot that we can utilize?

Comment: You can do that with virtual ips, and probably with a load balancer/reverse proxy. Failovers should never be handled by the application server itself.